# How to clean plugin dev cache in Intellij

Tags: caching, intellij-idea, clear-cache

I have a question about plugin development and IntelliJ. I'm developing a plugin to IntelliJ 12, and I have attached community sources. When I try to run my plugin (which has it own configuration under File → Settings → MyPlugin) and I check if configuration is visible, I don't see it. I know that it is working, because on another PC I checked it and configuration is visible (I didn't run the plugin earlier, it was first run, and configuration was visible).

I think that the IntellijJrun the configuration on the Community Edition which I have attached and on computer where I didn't saw configuration, I ran plugin few times before I have added that configuration.
When I run plugin, I see the message that cache wasn't cleared, and I think that this is the issue why I don't see configuration under File → Settings.

So the question is: how can I clear the cache on the testing instance of IntelliJ? I read that in IntelliJ 13 there is an option under File menu, but in 12, this option is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. If someone will want to clear their plugin development cache in IntelliJ 12, go to: `USER_HOME\.IntelliJIdea12\system` and remove the `plugins-sandbox` folder.